# Does Forcepoint Security Manager 8.5 (WebSense) allows SFTP petitions?

Tags: http-proxy, sftp

Can I use Forcepoint Security Manager 8.5 (WebSense) as an http proxy for my SFTP client connections to external Servers?

Currently when doing http requests I'm able to specify an http proxy to fetch external resources (Ex. google.maps) and it works fine. But, when try to use it on a SFTP Client it won’t work.

Does WebSense only work for http / https petitions?

Comment: I think this is a question for the vendor or the product manual

Answer (score 0):

Given that WebSense is a TLS intercepting proxy and SFTP is no TLS (but SSH instead) it is likely that it is not possible to use WebSense as a proxy for SFTP. Additionally there might be restrictions for arbitrary CONNECT requests, i.e. anything which is used to build some tunnel not to the typical web server ports.

This is just a guess though based on how many corporate TLS intercepting proxies like WebSense work. For details about the specific product please study the products documentation and/or ask the vendor support.